# why spring-boot keep all classes inside module `spring-boot-autoconfigure`

Tags: spring-boot

I noticed that spring-boot put all it's classes inside the sub module `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure`, and other sub modules like `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc` just do the dependency import without any class inside it. my question is that why don't spring-boot put the jdbc autoconfigure classes into the sub module `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` (so does other sub modules), so the code will be more cohesive.

Comment: An annoying side effect of this is that spring-boot will autoconfigure stuff in the dependencies even if I don't actually want it to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If Spring Boot did that, the the autoconfiguration would not be available if somebody decided to add required dependencies to their `pom.xml`/`build.gradle` directly rather than using starter module(s).

Edit: Since the comment section is growing exponentially, I'm answering OP's arguments here:

> I think this is not a problem, actually we expect users to use starter module(s) rather than required dependencies.

Who's "we"? Certainly not Spring developers, especially considering that starters are supposed to be a place to start, not a replacement for customized dependency list. For example spring-boot-starter-jdbc adds dependency on certain version HikariCP - but what if you prefer some other connection pool implementation or some other version of HikariCP. If autoconfiguration classes for JDBC were in the starter you'd have to configure excludes or not use autoconfiguration. The way it works now you can just remove the starter and add your preferred dependencies.

> OK, thanks for reply, what you say is very reasonable. But this still have some disadvantage, for example, if I want to use undertow, I can import spring-boot-starter-web and exclude spring-boot-starter-tomcat, and also I will import spring-boot-starter-undertow, then when spring-boot is upgraded to a newer version, if spring-boot-starter-web import a new dependency, I will have this dependency too

Any and all projects, regardless of programming language used, have dependencies on specific versions of libraries and frameworks, so there is never a situation that one or more dependencies somehow magically upgrage themselves and break the project's code. Furthermore, the dependencies and their versions are chosen at the beginning of the project and are not changed frequently, certainly not with every new release. Finally when the dependencies are switched or their versions raised it is done after researching the changes between currently used and new versions, precisely so no one ends in a situation where the software stops working because it suddenly needs a library that was not needed before.

> But if I do this in your way, I will not get the new dependency which is imported by spring-boot-starter-web, maybe I need to watch the source code and add this dependency myself. and also some developers don't know how to find out the dependencies of spring-boot-starter-web. The doc of spring-boot show this exclude demo: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.14.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-undertow-instead-of-tomcat

First, you do not need to watch the code - if you want to add all the dependencies from one of the Spring Boot starters, all you need to do is find them on [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org) or [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com) or another similar site and check what compile, optional and test dependencies they have and add whichever you need.

Second, no. I'm sorry, I do not want to sound like an asshole, but when it comes to their chosen programming language all software developers and software engineers know how to manage dependencies for their projects and check dependencies of 3rd party libraries or they simply would not be able to do their jobs.

Third, Spring Boot starters do not contain any code - only dependencies, so if the dependency is added to the starter, you most likely do not need it for anything in your project and if it's added to one the starter's dependencies, you'll get it aututomatically when you raise that dependencies version in your project (provided you set up dependency management correctly).

Comment: Who's "we"? Certainly not Spring developers, especially considering that starters are supposed to be a place to start, not a replacement for customized dependency list. For example `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` adds dependency on certain version `HikariCP` - but what if you prefer some other connection pool implementation or some other version of `HikariCP`. If autoconfiguration classes for JDBC were in the starter you'd have to configure excludes or not use autoconfiguration. The way it works now you can just remove the starter and add your preferred dependencies.

Comment: sorry, have you seen this doc: `https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.14.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-undertow-instead-of-tomcat`, it looks like that `spring-boot` tend to use `exclude`.